# CSS not applying on page overflow

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>

    <style>
        #div1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            min-width: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
            background: blue;
        }

        #div2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30%;
            left: 0px;
            width: 6000px;
            height: 300px;
            background: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For example in the html page above

[Starting view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jofeu.png)

[When scrolling to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDwBd.png)

I thought setting the div1 width to auto would match the div2 width but it does not work. Am I missing something? Do I need to auto update the width with javascript or can it be done with CSS only?

I want it cover the entire page even if the page gets resized.

Comment: Why not just set the outer div to be 6000px wide and the inner one to be 100% wide?

Comment: This is just an example. I want it to auto adjust in case I don't know the width of the child elements.

Comment: Do you want it to have the size of the window/page? Be more specific.

Comment: I want it cover the entire page even if the page gets resized.

Comment: It's still not clear. How do you want the 2 divs to be shown on the page?. What you have done now, div2 overlaps div1. Perhaps you could make an image of what you want, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position: relative` on `#div2`, `#div1` will then expand with it:

```css
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#div2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I can't believe I did not think of something so simple. I'm going to mark this answer as accepted when I'm able to.